# google maps geocoding не всегда верно определяет координаты

Tags: yandex-maps-api, google-maps, geocoding

Если я передаю такие параметры, то у меня не верно высчитывает координаты. Если я просто вставлю адрес в карту google map, то координаты высчитываются верно. Пожалуйста, скажите в чем проблема?
Пробовал добавлять &region=us&components=country:US, не помогло.

P.S. проблема возникает не со всеми адресами, но ведь в визуальной карте по адресу google/maps он правильно определяет адрес...

Код:

```
$address = '424 Rosevale Ave, Ronkonkoma, NY 11779, USA';
$xml_pos = file_get_contents('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address='.urlencode($address).'&key='.$api_key);
```

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется, что этот вопрос следует задавать не здесь, а в поддержку google. Хотя они конечно редко отвечают.
Но вряд ли кроме них кто-то сможет объяснить почему [обратное геокодирование](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) у них работает по разному в их продукте и их же API.

Хотя могу предположить, что причина чисто коммерческая - мол разрабатывайте на наших картах, а не на сторонних движках, тогда будет вам счастье.

Comment: Я Вас не понимаю. Какие сторонние движки? Если я использую стандартную функцию google maps api geocoding

Comment: @ИванЧуркин, Вы же не пишите приложение на основе библиотек google, а обращаетесь к их api из какого-то своего (или стороннего) приложения / движка / бекенда... Попробуйте сделать запрос через [api их карт](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro?hl=ru) (ещё [тык](https://habrahabr.ru/post/110460/)) не напрямую, а создать карту на их движке. И сравните результат.